# Trying to exclude some guids while hitting an endpoint

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest

I am hitting an endpoint using certain guids that I am receiving from a for loop. I would like to exclude some of the guids from hitting the endpoint.

```
async function main() {

    const url = validateURL(process.argv[2]);
    const origin = validatePath(process.argv[3]);
    const debug = validateDebug(process.argv[4]);
    let guid = 

    data = await getCategories(url, origin);
    result = data["results"];
    for (i = 0; i < result.length; i++) { 
        guid = result[i]["guid"];
        await legacyEndpoint(url,guid);
    }
}
main();
```

Is it possible to have a file with the list of guids I would like to ignore so when the loop is run it just leaves those guids ?

Thanks

```
async function main() {

    const url = validateURL(process.argv[2]);
    const origin = validatePath(process.argv[3]);
    const debug = validateDebug(process.argv[4]);
    let guid = 

    data = await getCategories(url, origin);
    result = data["results"];
    for (i = 0; i < result.length; i++) { 
        guid = result[i]["guid"];
        if (guid !== "32666424" || "489429571658" || "6803523795" || "489429571658"){
            await legacyEndpoint(url,guid);
        } else
        console.log("excluded");
    }
}
```

Comment: you can simply `require` a json file with guids in it.

Answer (score 0):

When checking your guid against the unallowed list, you can use Array.includes [JavaScript Array includes() Method](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_includes_array.asp) to ensure your guid is not in the unallowed list.

Something like so

```
async function main() {
    var unallowedGuids = ["32666424","489429571658","6803523795","489429571658"];
    const url = validateURL(process.argv[2]);
    const origin = validatePath(process.argv[3]);
    const debug = validateDebug(process.argv[4]);

    var data = await getCategories(url, origin);
    var result = data["results"];
    for (i = 0; i < result.length; i++) { 
        let guid = result[i]["guid"];
        if (!unallowedGuids.includes(guid)){
            await legacyEndpoint(url,guid);
        } 
        else
            console.log("excluded");
    }
}
```